# PHP web driver method to upload files to a remote machine running Selenium2 RC?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have a standalone selenium RC on a machine.
When I run tests, I would like to send a file over to that machine for upload.

Currently, in order to do this I have a predefined directory that I upload files to via rsync. My test code rsyncs the file over to the directory in the remote machine, then uses sendKeys() to send the remote file location to an input element in the DOM.

Obviously, this is not scalable as it does not take machine OS into account in any way, among other things. Does the standalone RC support FTP or using files from a URL as src to upload? Or is the feature that I'm looking for solely in the Java Selenium2 webdriver ([Local file detector class](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2012/03/selenium-tips-uploading-files-in-remote-webdriver/))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is more or less the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559728/uploading-files-remotely-on-selenium-webdriver-via-php)

The problem now is that the files need to be extracted out of the ZIP archive.

**Edit 6/2/2013**: The RC automatically extracts the contents of the ZIP archive and returns the file path on the remote machine in the JSON response.

Related:

- [php facebook webdriver PR](https://github.com/behance/php-webdriver/compare/HEAD)
- [phpunit selenium PR](https://github.com/chr0n1x/phpunit-selenium/compare/HEAD)